# How to insert data into MySQL database by using the GWT, HTML and JDBC or Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, html, hibernate, gwt-rpc

I am using the GWT(Google Web Tool-Kit) version 2.5.1. I am already done for develop sample application to display that username and password. But i am not identifying how to insert that values into MySQL database table by using JDBC of Hiberante. Any body know's that please send me complete code.

This is my mail-id:
subbareddyroyal@gmail.com

thanks & regards

Subbareddy.N

Answer (score 0):

GWT is NOT a java application environment.  It compiles to javascript.  You must send your data to a java server running in a full JVM.

Comment: i know your telling one.GWT is not a java environment.It compiles in javascript. That means not possible to insert values into mysql database table.

Comment: the compiled javascript code should reside on client side. But the data base operations should be performed by a pure java service through the DAOs using jdbc/hibernate/ibatis etc. So what yoou have to do is write client side VIEWS and then write RPC callbacks-Write Server side components and then write DAOs to insert data into mysql DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here above i am posting the question.My self i a finding the answer to insert values into my sql database by using the jdbc, GWT,and HTML.
Here i am posting that what i am changing in my application.

you add the below insert in you impl class under the server folder in gwt application.

```
public void insert(String name) throws CommunicationsException {
    try {
        System.out.println("Before loading the driver class");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("after loading the driver ");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gwt", "root", "root");
        System.out.println("after creating the connection");
        PreparedStatement ps = con
                .prepareStatement("insert into gwt_user(userName)values(?)");
        System.out.println("after loading the query");
        ps.setString(1, name);


        int i = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (i < 0) {
            return;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

after that you can add the  below try catch block in ur greetserver(optional Name) method under the impl class.

```
       try {
        insert(name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then remaining all files are same.No need to change any file in your application